# pop_back() not working

Tags: c++, stack, deque

I have the following main program that creates a `Stack` object, fills it with doubles and then pops them. The code files fine, but the `pop_back()` part does not seem to work, while `s.back()` does return the correct value. How is this possible?

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  Stack<double> s(0,0.0);

  // Write doubles into Stack
  int i ;
  for (i=0 ; i<15 ; i++) {

    s.push(i*i) ;

  }


  // Read doubles back from fifo
  while (!s.empty()) {
    double val = s.pop() ;
    std::cout << "Popping value " << val << " from stack" << std::endl ;

  }

  return 0 ;

}
```

My header file looks like this, where I have omitted parts which are not relevant to the question.

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <deque>  

template<class T>
class Stack {

public:  

  Stack(int len, T defval): s(len+1, defval) {

    return;
}

~Stack() {

    //delete [] s;
}

void push(T c) {

    s.push_back(c);

}

T pop() {

    return s.back();
    s.pop_back();  

}

private:   

  std::deque<T> s; //Array<T> s;  

};

#endif
```

Comment: Your `return` is __before__ the `pop_back`

Comment: your `pop()` function returns before `s.pop_back()` is called.

Comment: Please, do three things: 1. enable all compiler warnings, 2. set them as errors and 3. also try compiling with optimizations. That should detect the problem. Unfortunately, you have to include 3., because in some compilers, dead code is only detected during optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
T pop() {
    return s.back();
//  ^^^^^

    s.pop_back(); // <- unreachable! 
}
```

When you `return` from a function, all the subsequent instruction will **never be executed**.

---

Store `s.back()`'s result in a temporary variable instead:

```
T pop() {
    auto back = s.back();
    s.pop_back();  
    return back;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works now. However, the function now returns a small random number instead of the correct double.

Comment: Fixed it by replacing `val` by `s.pop()`.